# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from sum(_c9#30);

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark sql to select a column along with sum of another column:
Below is my query:

```
scala> spark.sql("select distinct _c3,sum(_c9).as(sumAadhar)  from aadhar group by _c3 order by _c9 desc LIMIT 3").show
```

And my schema is :

```
    root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c6: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c7: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c9: double (nullable = true)
 |-- _c10: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c11: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c12: string (nullable = true)
```

And I a getting below error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from sum(_c9#30);
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExtractValue$.apply(complexTypeExtractors.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:613)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:605)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:308)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:308)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:305)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:305)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:328)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:186)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:305)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:269)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:279)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:283)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
```

Any idea, what am i doing wrong or is there any other way to sum the values of a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below which is tried on a reduced schema:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("a", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 4), ("a", 9), ("b", 1), ("c", 100)).toDF("_c3", "_c9") df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c3: string, _c9: int]

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("aadhar")

scala> spark.sql("select _c3,sum(_c9) as sumAadhar from aadhar group by _c3 order by sumAadhar desc LIMIT 3").show
+---+---------+ 
|_c3|sumAadhar|
+---+---------+ 
|  c|      100| 
|  a|       14| 
|  b|        5|
+---+---------+
```

- Removed `distinct` since its not necessary as your original query already groups by _c3.
- Changed `sum(_c9).as(sumAadhar)` to `sum(_c9) as sumAadhar` as I think that syntax was leading spark sql to do some unintended casting.

Comment: Getting Same error:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`_c9`' given input columns: [_c3, sum(CAST(_c9 AS DOUBLE))]; line 1 pos 55;

Comment: But when I use alias it is working fine:
spark.sql("select _c3,sum(_c9) as total from adh group by _c3 order by total LIMIT 3").show

Comment: @KumarHarsh, from your last comment, seems like the solution has worked for you. If so, consider marking as answer.